# How do I call a website using a c# process in kiosk mode on Edge Chromium?

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am using the following command to open a website in Kiosk Mode

```
Proc = Process.Start(browser, "--kiosk --incognito https://example.net/PPT" + CC + "?" + Msg);
```

This used to work without issue on a windows 10 tablet, however recent upgrades to edge chromium / windows now prevent the site from opening in kiosk mode.

The process is initiated by the detection of an NFC fob.

I have noticed that if I represent the fob (whilst the site is open), which causes the process to be stopped and restarted, the command works as expected.

Comment: What does it mean to "call a website"?

Comment: The c# program executes the command above, which starts edge chromium and opens the website whose url is specified in the command above, in kiosk mode

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, why are you here?

Comment: The command used to work, but now ignores the request for kiosk mode. So this could be a bug introduced into edge chromium as Microsoft have enhanced it. Has anyone else out there experienced the same issue?